# Considering the order of instanciation when inheriting from a base class, how does Java know when to override a class method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, instantiation

I am taking an introduction to OOP (Java) in university and encountered the following code:

```java
// This example program aims at inspecting and understanding the order in which the individual 
// initialization steps are taken when executing this program.

public class ConstructorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sub();
    }
}

class Super {
    Super() {
        System.out.println("Super constructor");
        m();
    }

    void m() {
        System.out.println("Method m() of class Super");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    Person p = new Person();

    Sub() {
        System.out.println("Sub constructor");
        m();
    }

    @Override
    void m() {
        System.out.println("Method m() of class Sub");
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}

class Person {
    String name;

    String getName() {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}
```

The output to the code will be the following:

```
"Super constructor"
"Method m() of class Sub"
NullPointerException
```

The NullPointerException occurs because `p.getName()` cannot be invoked since `Person p = new Person()` is instantiated with null. (This is on purpose!)

The program is executed in the following order:

1. The main method in the `ConstructorTest` class is executed.
2. `new Sub()` is called, which invokes the constructor of the `Sub` class.
3. The `Sub` class constructor starts executing.
4. Since the Sub class extends the `Super` class, the superclass constructor `Super()` is called before the body of the `Sub` class constructor.
5. Inside the `Super` class constructor: 
   a) The line `System.out.println("Super constructor");` prints "Super constructor" to the console. 
   b) The method `m()` is called. Since the `Sub` class overrides this method, the overridden version in the `Sub` class will be invoked. However, at this point, the `Sub` class constructor has not finished executing yet.
6. The control goes back to the `Super` class constructor, and the constructor execution completes.
7. The control returns to the `Sub` class constructor.
8. The line `Person p = new Person();` is encountered.
9. The `Person` class constructor is invoked, which doesn't have any explicit output.
10. The instance of the `Person` class is created and assigned to the `p` instance variable.
11. The control goes back to the `Sub` class constructor, and the constructor execution completes.
12. The line `System.out.println("Sub constructor");` in the `Sub` class constructor is executed, printing "Sub constructor" to the console.
13. The `m()` method is called again, this time within the `Sub` class constructor.
14. Inside the overridden `m()` method in the `Sub` class: 
    a) The line `System.out.println("Method m() of class Sub");` is executed, printing "Method m() of class Sub" to the console. 
    b) The line `System.out.println(p.getName());` is executed, which calls the `getName()` method on the initialized `p` instance of the `Person` class and prints "John Doe" to the console.

Now to my question:

When invoking the `Super` class constructor, Java first prints `System.out.println("Super constructor");` to the console. In the next step, it would call `Super.m()`. However, since `Super.m()` gets overridden in the `Sub` class, it calls `Sub.m()` instead.
How does Java know that the `Sub` class overrides the method `m()` from the `Super` class if the order of instantiation dictates that the super class constructor has to be invoked BEFORE the sub class constructor? Does it recursively check each base class method for a subclass method of the same name? Is the Sub class "scanned" prior to instantiating the base class, and thus Java knows how to handle a base class method when it encounters it upon instantiation?

Basically, I would like to get a better understanding of what happens behind the scenes, when Java overrides a class method.

Comment: Those overrides happen at compile time, not at runtime. You are still instantiating a `Sub`, so that's the method that is called. There is no need to search for anything at runtime.

Comment: Overriding has nothing to do with the order of instantiation. Why do you think they are related?

Comment: @Sweeper From our script: 

"The basic principle in the initialization of a new object of a class K is that, from Object descending in the class hierarchy down to K itself, at least one constructor is executed per class. Any initializations at a particular class level occur only after all initializations at the level above are completed". My understanding is that for sub to be initialized, first Super has to be initialized, meaning that its constr. is invoked BEFORE Sub's constr. is. So how does java know it must override Super m() if it invokes sub constr after super?

Comment: None of what you quoted says anything about overriding.

Comment: A great question, this is due to _static initialization_ of _Super_ via the declaration of class _Sub_.  _class Sub extends Super_.

Comment: Note that this is all different from C++ where `Super.m()` would have been called, because the vtable is constructed progressively. This doesn't happen in Java, it is all built at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that the initialization of the class metadata depends on the initialization of the object, but this is not the case. Classes are initialized before the first instance of this class is created and all instances share the class data.

E.g. when you run the following program

```java
public class Super {
    public void method1() {}
    public void method2() {}
}
```

```java
public class Sub extends Super {
    @Override public void method2(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        System.out.println(Sub.class.getMethod("method1").getDeclaringClass());
        System.out.println(Sub.class.getMethod("method2").getDeclaringClass());
    }
}
```

It will print

```
class Super
class Sub
```

demonstrating that it is known which method has been overridden, even if no instance of this class exists. (The classes and methods have to be `public` for this example to work)

[online demonstration](https://tio.run/##nVCxasMwEN3zFUcmaaihWbsU2o5JB40lg2wdthLLEtLJdTD@dle2kzTQUGhvOXjv3XvcO8hWPhzUcRxdzGtdQFHLEGArdQP9CtKc8UCS0mqtVmASywR53ZQfe5C@DByo8vYzwM6KWFRbpMqqt65AR9penKYRp0BoMhspc@me6mQU82xOzUqk5ZKtzbwf13wCXzHxU9rLJGMzJrRxNe6kQcb50z/9N3/yH277WHoS0aG/ee9MLi0tLzAO/fCLYPMtuBuQA3aEjfoZ9vzeovda4X3Xq@kwjl8) (uses inner classes to put two public classes in one file)

We can also demonstrate that each object is invariably an instance of its class, regardless of the execution of the constructors:

```java
public class Sub extends Super {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        new Sub();
    }
}
class Super {
    Super() {
        System.out.println("Constructing object of type " + getClass());
    }
}
```

prints

```
Constructing object of type class Sub
```

When you execute `new Sub()`, two things happen:

- First, memory is allocated for an instance of `Sub`, large enough to hold all instance fields belong to `Sub` (including inherited fields). The object’s meta data is initialized to indicate that it is an instance of `Sub` (think of an unchangeable pointer to the class metadata) and all fields initialized to the default value for its type (zero, `false`, or `null`).
- Then, the constructor is executed. This includes the execution of the field initializer and initializer blocks, which happens after the `super` constructor call but before any other statement of the constructor.
  The super constructor may invoke overridden methods, as discussed, but it’s usually not a good idea to invoke overridable methods in a constructor, as these overridden methods will see the fields of the the subclass in their default state.

```java
public class Sub extends Super {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        new Sub();
    }

    int value = 10;

    @Override
    void method() {
        System.out.println("value = " + value);
    } 
}
class Super {
    Super() {
        System.out.println("Constructing object of type " + getClass());
        method();
    }
    void method() {}
}
```

prints

```
Constructing object of type class Sub
value = 0
```

[online demonstration](https://tio.run/##hVCxasMwFNz9FY9MMqWhmUOgEDqmHTyWDrL0ast1JCE9OQkh3@7IskUzFHqL3juhu9N1fODPnfwZRxvqXgkQPfceDlxpuBYQsfCeOMVjMErCMd6yipzSzecXcNf4Eqh15uTh3VRBtAek1si3s0BLymSlCRpPUIWaldtE3YpbMTtGEvBMqOU0W3TLI6UJBt4HhB1sXrZFIl8/BnROSUzbnClZsvLBq7p4wuPaBFrbmJV6zVZZagVPs2wOAg9Jft3T/K/o3mhPLgiKhYCpOxQE5hvoYjEZNUj7SZqVi9uEHDgX8cdPYjvjeAc)

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. Now it makes sense! I will mark this as the solution to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a *static initialization*.  This will occur when the compiler requires the resource.
*[Initializing Fields (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)*.

In this case, during the following declaration.

```java
class Sub extends Super
```

So, the steps are, as follows.

1. *Sub* constructor method called from *main*
2. *Super* static initialization, since *Sub* extends *Super*
3. *Sub* static initialization, since this is always called before the class's initial instantiation
4. *Super* constructor method, since *Sub* extends *Super*
5. Finally, *m*, of *Sub*, since your calling from *Sub*

> *"... How does Java know that the `Sub` class overrides the method `m()` from the `Super` class if the order of instantiation dictates that the super class constructor has to be invoked BEFORE the sub class constructor? ..."*

For example, add a *static initialization block* to each class.

```java
static {
    System.out.println("super, static initialization");
}
```

Output

```
super, static initialization
sub, static initialization
Super constructor
Method m() of class Sub
```

Comment: The static initialization happens before the constructor invocation.

Comment: @Holger, _"Sub constructor method called ..."_.

Comment: I don’t know what you want say with your comment. You list “Sub constructor method called from main” as first step, before the static initialization, which is wrong. The execution of the static initializer happens before any constructor is called, even before the object’s memory is allocated. But the knowledge about overriding does not depend on the execution of the static initializer anyway.

Comment: Which can be demonstrated with [this example program](https://tio.run/##rVKxboNADN37FVYmUFWkZmyXSmmHDkkHxqrDHbjgBO7QYUjaKN9O74C0FJG0Q24B2c/v2c9ei1rcrONN0xSVzCiCKBNlCUtBCvZXYF8fL1mw/dSaYsht1gvZkEpe30CYpPSBU6O3Jax0WEXpEjnV8dMuwoJJH5ncCz9KxjzQFQeFredMebO8Rd/ewQyuIaxk0PYQJMgdzzdi5rvgI9q80144mNfGQsqLDFciR8/37/@hNv9TbX4RtYVB65tKnBKQsi6qCGeDIoVbl/P60GHC824lYVWgGTjZJ/eTsn2SFDGJjD5tpX7vKKx4r9L27EKef4Km04y07dtUEetRcd9mdxPdihzVOcD8B3BuVAm4Y1TxhcaW46FlOzKnVHqD6Z5VrTcYu6WesEMOzbD/7g4Y45EthmrB2MpIrTMUCuQvXx5eajSGYpx2aIDsJzrSTDU7MOfUFY4bp652eIfuGeTKKLAo/Ekcl3Vomi8). It shows declaring classes w/o initializer

Comment: @Holger, that's great.  Write an answer.

Comment: Well, I already did.

Comment: @Holder, I'm not interested in refutable arguments, take your comments elsewhere.

Comment: I provided a proof for what I wrote. You did not.